How to programmatically enable the small taskbar in Windows 11
Windows 11 still has small taskbars
I tried the registry editor but it did not work. For example, TaskbarSi Dword creation in the regedit didn't work also. I even used the 3rd party Vevotool and even that did not work. I decided the taskbar Windows Explorer and still did not fix the problem. Popular solutions to the problem include going to Windows update and signing up for Windows insider program beta channel however I do not want this because in order to get out of the beta channel I have to do a clean install of my system.
